# Why does the URL include /blog/ on one of my Multisite WP sites and not the other?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, permalinks

Can some one tell me why I have one Multisite that includes a /blog/ in the url and the other one doesn't?

EG:

http://site1.com/blog/article

http://site2.com/article

How can I change this on a site by site basis?

And when I change it how should a redirect the current URLs to the new location.

What is the code for .htaccess file?

Thanks! :)

Comment: have you replaced the .htaccess with the generated code while install the Multi Site ?

Comment: # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Comment: No this `RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]`

Answer (score 0):

if you used the subdirectory install of WPMU the .htaccess must like the below

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: That is the same as I pasted above... Just the comment wouldn't let me format it... :)
So that is not the cause of the issue as far as I can see...

Comment: hello check it again , there is the difference between each other

Comment: OK... I have updated the .htaccess file and it hasn't made any difference??? Any more ideas?

Comment: have you defined your multisite configuration in `wp-config.pjp` ?

Comment: Yes...
/* Multisite */
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'alanbrandt.com');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);